# Multiple Interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to input 2 interfaces to a class so that I may return information from them, in this case, an age and a name. However I have run into a problem where my C1 class does not have a matching return type of int, and I don't understand what to do now as any examples I've seen only had 1 interface or multiple classes. Here is what I have so far:

```
interface IWhatsMyAgeAgain
{
    int GetAge();
}

interface ISayMyName
{
    string GetName();
}

class C1 : IWhatsMyAgeAgain, ISayMyName
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
    public string GetName() {return Name;}
    public int GetAge() {return Age;}
}


class Program
{
    static void PrintInfo (IWhatsMyAgeAgain item, ISayMyName Item )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age {1}", Item.GetName(), item.GetAge() );
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        C1 a = new C1() { Name = "Tom", Age = 29 };
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't fix the code in the question to match what is given in the answers, since it makes the question impossible to understand for new people reading this page.

Answer (score 0):

`IWhatsMyAgeAgain`'s `GetAge` method returns `int` but your class returns `string`, change it to this:

```
class C1 : IWhatsMyAgeAgain, ISayMyName
{
    public int    Age;
    public string Name;

    public string GetName() { return Name; }
    public int    GetAge() { return Age; }
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists and I get a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' Error.

Comment: `Age.ToString()` is not an `int`. You should just be returning `Age`.

Comment: GetAge should return Age, not Age.ToString

Comment: Okay I have changed the code, (edited in question to what I have now) and when it runs nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: That's because you're not calling PrintInfo()